# How can pass product id from Product\Form\Modifier to UiComponent DataProvider in Admin PRODUCT DETAIL

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-detail-page

This is Tab "Staff Manager" have display but can't receive Product Id
[image]
**view/adminhtml/ui_component
/staff_listing.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">staff_listing.staff_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">staff_listing.staff_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">staff_columns</item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="staff_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="test"/>
    </settings>
    <dataProvider class="Custom\Staff\Ui\DataProvider\StaffDataProvider" name="staff_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters_modifier" xsi:type="array"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <statefull>
                <property name="applied" xsi:type="boolean">false</property>
            </statefull>
        </settings>
    </filters>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">staff_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">staff_listing.staff_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">staff_listing.staff_listing.amasty_customform_answer_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="staff_columns" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <settings>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <column name="id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

**Ui/DataProvider/StaffDataProvider**

```
    <?php
    namespace Custom\Staff\Ui\DataProvider;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
    use Custom\Staff\Model\ResourceModel\Staff\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder as ProductBuilder;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\PoolInterface;
    /**
     * Class StaffDataProvider
     */
    class StaffDataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
    {
        protected $collection;
        protected $addFieldStrategies;
        protected $addFilterStrategies;
        protected $request;
        protected $registry;
        protected $productBuilder;
        protected $pool;
        public function __construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
            RequestInterface $request,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            ProductBuilder $productBuilder,
            PoolInterface $pool,
            array $meta = [],
            array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
            $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->registry = $registry;
            $this->pool = $pool;
            $this->productBuilder = $productBuilder;
            $this->data = $data;
        }
        public function getCollection(){  
            return $this->collection;
        }
        public function getData(){     
            foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
                $this->data = $modifier->modifyData($this->data);
            }
            return $this->data;
        }
        public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
        {
            $field = $filter->getField();
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
        public function getMeta()
        {
            $meta = parent::getMeta();

            foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
                $meta = $modifier->modifyMeta($meta);
            }

            return $meta;
        }
    }
```

**Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier**

```
<?php 
namespace Custom\Staff\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier; 
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface; 
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier; 
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager; 
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface; 
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container; 
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\PoolInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager as ModuleManager;
class Staff extends AbstractModifier { 
    const SAMPLE_FIELDSET_NAME = 'staff_listing_fieldset'; 
    const SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME = 'staff_listing'; 
    const GROUP_REVIEW = 'staff';
    const GROUP_CONTENT = 'content';
    const SORT_ORDER = 20;
    const LINK_TYPE = 'associated';
    protected $_backendUrl; 
    protected $_productloader; 
    protected $_modelCustomgridFactory; 
    private $moduleManager;
    protected $locator; 
    protected $arrayManager; 
    protected $urlBuilder; 
    protected $meta = [];
    public function __construct( LocatorInterface $locator, ArrayManager $arrayManager, UrlInterface $urlBuilder, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader, \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl ) { $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta){
        if (!$this->locator->getProduct()->getId() || !$this->getModuleManager()->isOutputEnabled('Custom_Staff')) {
            return $meta;
        }
        $meta[static::GROUP_REVIEW] = [
            'children' => [
                'staff_listing' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'autoRender' => true,
                                'componentType' => 'insertListing',
                                'dataScope' => 'staff_listing',
                                'externalProvider' => 'staff_listing.staff_listing_data_source',
                                'selectionsProvider' => 'staff_listing.staff_listing.product_columns.ids',
                                'ns' => 'staff_listing',
                                'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render/'),
                                'update_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('test'),
                                'realTimeLink' => true,
                                'dataLinks' => [
                                    'imports' => false,
                                    'exports' => true
                                ],
                                'behaviourType' => 'simple',
                                'externalFilterMode' => true,
                                'id_product' => $this->locator->getProduct()->getId(),
                                'imports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.current_product_id'
                                ],
                                'exports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id'
                                ],
                                // 'imports' => [
                                //     'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id'
                                // ],
                                // 'exports' => [
                                //     'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id'
                                // ],

                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Staff Manager'),
                        'sortOrder' => 1,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'sortOrder' =>
                        $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                            $meta,
                            static::GROUP_CONTENT,
                            static::SORT_ORDER
                        ),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $meta;
    }
    public function modifyData(array $data){
        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_product_id'] = $productId;
        return $data;
    }
    private function getModuleManager()
    {
        if ($this->moduleManager === null) {
            $this->moduleManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ModuleManager::class);
        }
        return $this->moduleManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ***`function getData()`*** in **`Ui/DataProvider/StaffDataProvider`** is called by Magento 2 times.
The first call is made by GET to **`{{domain_admin}}/mui/index/render/?namespace=staff_listing&isAjax=true`**,
in which only ***`$this->request->getParams()`*** the namespace variable and isAjax appear.
And in the **second call is made by POST** and receives more parameters. Among them, the **current_product_id**

Comment: any solution found yet for this as i can't able to get `current_product_id` in post param.even it is not passed in the params.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some parts in your code

**Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier**

uncomment this part

```
                            // 'imports' => [
                            //     'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id'
                            // ],
                            // 'exports' => [
                            //     'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id'
                            // ],
```

**Ui/DataProvider/StaffDataProvider**

```
public function getData(){
        // here you can get current_product_id
        $productId  = $this->request->getParam('current_product_id', 0);
 
        foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
            $this->data = $modifier->modifyData($this->data);
        }
        return $this->data;
    }
```